# unix find command Permission issues in result

Tags: unix, find

In Unix,
when i execute

```
$ find . -name 'Export.class' -print
```

Displays,

```
The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.
find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to </usr/.ibm>:
```

the errors should not be displayed in console. Only the result is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you asking how to "turn off" the errors? Because if so it's done like this:

```
$ find . -name 'Export.class' -print 2>/dev/null
```

This redirects stderr to /dev/null so you won't see it, leaving you with just the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find . -name 'Export.class' -print 2>/dev/null
```

`2>` redirecting the standard error into `/dev/null`.